Как в 1с битрикс создать страницу с калькулятором цен на товар в зависимости от выбранных компонентов?
Сейчас работаю с 1с битрикс.
Не могу найти в документации или интернете, как создать калькулятор цены товара на основе параметров. Например, если цвет красный, то цена 500, если зеленая, то 400. Дизайна у меня нет, пока не нуждаюсь.
Создал инфоблок с такими параметрами.


Как мне сделать так, чтобы от разных параметров зависела цена?
Как мне вывести эту информацию на страницу?

Прошу подробнее, так как совсем недавно начал изучать битрикс.

Вы такое и не найдете) это индивидуальный код обычно) Написать калькулятор ШкОльНикА - или написать универсальный калькулятор для всех возможных задач (физика, геометрия, алхимия..).. что может быть проще?.. Не знаком с битрикс, чисто из теории) вам нужно выдернуть в JS (браузер) изначальные данные из 1C и потом в JS динамически строить нужные поля в разметке браузера) либо втрой вариант (как по мне не очень).. загружать на страницу базовую информацию,.. при изменении дергать сервер к примеру по AJAX и подставлять данные) второй вариант если нельзя палить формулы.. все будет на сервере

При первом варианте, формулы подсчета уже будут в JS, либо вы их должны так же подгружать индивидуально для пользователя в браузер) Вариант с загрузкой формул и данных в браузер лично мне нравится больше, лишних запросов к серверу будет меньше, да и вычислять каждый пользователь будет себе сам

Это товарные предложения для товаров, и у каждого товарного предложения указывается своя цена.

@Jour, спасибо, я понимаю вашу идею) К сожалению мне досталась возможность работать с битриксом, за пару дней я сильно пропитался к нему ненавистью

@u_mulder, такое бы сработало, будь расширение "магазин" или же уровень "бизнес", а такого нет.

Ну тогда добавь поле Цена в инфоблок.

@FroggerProgger ну да, битрикс ненавидят наверное все, кто с ним работал) За 17 лет моего участия в сфере IT, ни одного лестного отзыва не слышал об этой системе, все через боль и с бубном.. Да и сама 1C как бы не плохой инструмент.. но коммерция убила комьюнити.. проще заказать на ларавель (к примеру) полный набор, под конкретную индивидуально заточенную задачу, чем ЛюБиТсЯ с 1С да еще и постоянно кому-то сто-то платить.. ну такое

@Jour к сожалению после учебы попал в компанию. На меня повесили работу с битриксом. Говорят, что мол такая программа, которую я попросил помочь сделать, будет классной.
Я не спорю, идея у них хорошая, но я в душе не чаю, как это сделать на битриксе со странном подключением компонентов, их структурой. Сам разработать могу, но без него.

@FroggerProgger мб пусть дадут документацию на ПО (1С) где есть аналогичный пример.. потом дадут четкое ТЗ (тех задание).. за адекватную цену и время задачи вполне реализуема) чисто на вскидку, цена вопроса =  пол года и примерно 30-50 тысяч долларов бюджета на 1 разраба) если взять сразу контору будет и дешевле и быстрее... не факт что качественнее.. Пользуйтесь (с)

@Jour большое спасибо вам за совет)
